# Closing DDE server connection in python?

Tags: python, dde

Yes, I know that DDE is beyond ancient technology, however, it's what I have to use... :(

My problem is that I cannot 'cleanly' close the 'conversation', and disconnect from the server.

I'm using dde.py that (I think) comes with python. Right now after my script runs, if I run it again, I get the error "The server could not be created" after server.Create("xxxx") is run... If I close python and restart, everything runs again.

Thoughts?